# Include additional attachment blob to existing messages attachments in MailApp.sendEmail

Tags: gmail-api

I am using MailApp sendEmail in Google Apps Scripts to fetch an existing email, send it to another different address, with attachments, but also adding the message.getrawcontent() as additional attachment as txt file. I am not able to add element (i.e. attachment) to the blobsource[] array. Thereby, I am either able to send the txt file attachment of message.getrawcontent() or the original attachments, but not both.

I have creating creating an array of existing and new attachments but it does not work. I have creating creating an array such as 
[messages[m].getAttachments(), blob] 
but it does not work.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to: email,subject: ThisMessageSubject,htmlBody: messages[m].getBody(),attachments: [messages[m].getAttachments(), blob],});
```

I am hoping to get both, the original messages[m] attachments as well as blob attachment as txt of messages[m].getrawcontent()

Comment: Hello. Still struggling. According to the GAS Documentation on sendEmail, the attachments argument requires a BlobSource[]. So an associated question would be, how can I forward (or freshly send) message with selective attachments. The crux is to be able to play around with the blobsource[] array, i.e. add or reduce elements (individual attachments) to it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello.  I made further attempts adding files one by one in a for loop, and failed at that also. Any help appreciated.

Comment: For now, I am making a compromise. Including the additional attachment that I wanted, since it is a text file, in the mail body. There doesn't seem to be any documentation about it.